# Tracking down DEBUG logged entries

Tags: magento-1, log, debugging, debug

We've recently inherited a mess of a Magento store with a new client that has come to us and there are thousands of `DEBUG` entries being written to log every minute.

They don't give a lot to go on from what is being written to log (below screenshot) and just wondered what the quickest way you could recommend would be, to track down just where these are coming from in the system?

Short of searching for `Mage::log()` or running a diff check on the entire site, I am unsure what else I can try.

[image: Debug entries written to Magento log]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Find out which URL is triggering the log

Edit `app/Mage.php` and replace the following code under the `log()` method:

```
$loggers[$file]->log($message, $level);
```

With:

```
$loggers[$file]->log(self::$_app->getRequest()->getControllerName(), $level);
$loggers[$file]->log(self::$_app->getRequest()->getActionName(), $level);
$loggers[$file]->log(self::$_app->getRequest()->getRouteName(), $level);
$loggers[$file]->log(self::$_app->getRequest()->getModuleName(), $level);
$loggers[$file]->log($message, $level);
```

This should help you find out the location of the problem.

### The hard way

Assuming you haven't rewritten any core files you can do the following in your console:

```
cd app/code/community
grep -ri "mage::log(" .
cd ../local
grep -ri "mage::log(" .
cd ../../design
grep -ri "mage::log(" .
```

This should give you a good list on where to look.

### The softer hard way ^^

Open `app/Mage.php` and rename the `log` function with something else, example:

```
public static function nolog($message, $level = null, $file = '', $forceLog = false)
```

Reload your page you will get an exception such as:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage::log() in /path/to/the/file/calling/the/log/function
```

With a full stack trace.

This way you will get directly which file is trying to call the `Mage::log()` method.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I actually tracked down the screenshot in my question quite quickly just by searching for `Mage::log(` but some of these others are proving much more difficult :/

Comment: The next one is proving difficult (tried a search in all code pools but could not see the cause) - the path to every used `.xml` file is being logged (not on every page load, not sure which page load).

Comment: @zigojacko I've found another way of doing it check my updated answer

Comment: Finally got round to trying your second solution but if I think what you're saying is that this requires a refresh of the page in the frontend to throw the stack trace? Which if is the case, I can't because I have no idea what URL's or process is causing all the `DEBUG` entries in the `system.log`. I tried reloading the homepage, categories, products, CMS pages, checkout after modifying the `log` function to `nolog` but did not see any new or useful information unfortunately.

Comment: @zigojacko I've made an update to help you to find out which URL is causing the problem. Thus, next time it is supposed to into your file, it will add extra info

Comment: Unfortunately that still doesn't help, it is now printing category, view, catalog, catalog and then the absolute path to the XML file (then all five lines repeated for every single XML file being loaded in the site). Thanks for the efforts though.

Comment: @zigojacko yeah that's exactly what I expected that means that works. The error is triggered by the category pages (route = `catalog/category/view` ) you now know what pages are trigerring the error

Comment: That was just an example (sorry), it throws the same debugging on index/index, cms/cms etc etc too. Heh.

Comment: @zigojacko In that case that means the logging is triggered on every page. Could be something to do with the Head or Footer, blocks that appears on every page of the website

Comment: Yes, that is what I figured but it is nothing in the theme (already checked) - found someone else with exactly the same issue [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92707/debug-7-all-xml-files-in-base-default-layout), unanswered. Still looking... :/

Comment: Bingo!! Finally found it. Core file had been edited with `Mage::log($filename);` in `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php` around line 450 (Magento CE 1.9.2.1). Wow, that was a mission - thanks for all your help @Raphael.

Comment: @zigojacko yeah glad we figured it out =) don't forget to remove the changes I told you to apply

Comment: Yep, already removed all my/our debugging to track this down. Cheers.